# How to trigger bootstrap modal in drupal 8 website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want to show some data in a dialog box on my drupal 8 website. I am not able to figure it out even after reading so many tutorials. None of them described how to use all bootstrap components. I am using custom bootstrap theme. I have a content type which i want to show in bootstrap modal on clicking on a link.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a post about how to use the modal API in Drupal 8, hope this helps

https://blog.42mate.com/using-drupal-8-modal-api/